# Setting SSH to use key only, not passwords

Tags: ssh

So we have a server, and you can ssh into it. However, we set up public encryption keys. We want the ONLY way to login is with an authenticated key. No possible way to login using password. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

```
passwd -l account
```

seems to make it impossible to log in to an account without the ssh key.

Answer (score 2):

Set all other authentication types `no` in `sshd_config`.

```
RSAAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the line `PasswordAuthentication no` to /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Probably depends on OS